# Is there a way to review all my questions that have been deleted by the community?

Tags: support, search, deleted-questions

I know that there is a link for recently deleted questions.  This link does not provide the complete list.

I was going through the reputation link and I noticed that I have a number of questions that have been removed by the community that are not included in the link of recently deleted questions.

Is there any way (other than going through the reputation, clicking the down arrow, and looking for details on what was removed), to find out the list of all questions that have been deleted?

I am interested in reviewing them and making sure that my future questions don't make the same mistakes.

I know that other folks have asked the same question.  None of the answers talked about using the link to the reputation history that is available on a user's profile.  Is the link to the reputation history to trace through the list of "removed" questions?

---

Edit:  Updated my question.

Comment: It is actually "deleted  recent" not "recently deleted" that is the post must be recent not the event of deletion.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19689/how-to-find-old-deleted-posts-of-my-own http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6707/can-i-view-all-recent-deletions-especially-self-deleted-questions?rq=1 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions?rq=1 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/suggest-adding-complete-list-of-recently-deleted-posts?lq=1

Comment: Good point quid.  One of my questions was deleted recently but was not a recent post.  @Najib, thanks for the post.  I read through all those questions and was surprised that no one mentioned the option of traversing the reputation link.  They all suggest that it can't be done (when I know that traversing the reputation link is available).  So, let me ask it another way:  Is traversing the reputation history the only way to do it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, reputation link does not give all deleted questions either. Some questions are deleted after 365 days without any votes at all, and consequently without reputation changes.

Comment: Thanks @Woodface.  So, the answer is that the reputation links provides more than the "recently deleted"  but doesn't include deleted questions that don't involve a change in reputation score.  There is no way for a non-moderator to see the complete list of deleted questions.

Comment: @Woodface or after 60 days with score at least 3 (in which case one keeps the points).

Answer (score 7):

This has been implemented for 10k+ users: [Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users) (meta.SE).

So you can search for [user:me deleted:1 is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1+is%3Aq) to see your deleted questions and for [user:me deleted:1 is:a](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1+is%3Aa) to see your deleted answer. Or you can try simply [user:me deleted:1](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1) to get all your deleted posts (both questions and answers).

In fact, you can omit user:me. When you try any of the queries, there is a message saying: *"Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content.*" See also the bug reports [10K+ users can [still] search any user's deleted content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/10k-users-can-still-search-any-users-deleted-content) and [10K+ users can search any user's deleted content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270554/10k-users-can-search-any-users-deleted-content) on meta.SE.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, a user can't obtain a list of all their deleted questions (or answers) by themselves.

You have access to a list of deleted *recent* questions/answers from the corresponding tab in your profile, but that only includes posts that are - iirc - at most 60 days old.

You can find your self-deleted posts from the [votes tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=deletion) in your profile (in your case, that is the majority of your deleted questions, 10 out of 14). That stops working well, however, when one has the privilege to vote to delete other people's posts and uses that privilege a lot and one's own posts become a small minority of the deletion votes.

Community - or [Community♦](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) - deleted posts, you can find from the reputation tab in your profile if the deletion causes a reputation change, provided you have checked the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of that tab, e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741378/if-pa-equiv-1-pmod-qb-is-there-anything-that-we-can-say-about-a-if) - which was deleted recently enough that finding it in that way is practicable - but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482943/a-question-about-the-order-of-2-in-the-reduced-residue-system-of-a-fracp) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458661/least-prime-factor-of-a-ceiling-function-that-involves-primorials) would require some determination to track down. And posts like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380029/does-it-follow-that-if-fracx2-ge-frac12-frac-x-2-lo) which don't cause a reputation change upon deletion cannot be tracked via the reputation tab.

If one asks nicely and there aren't too many<sup>(1)</sup> deleted posts, one can often get a list from a moderator.

<sup>(1)</sup> Making a list of hundreds of posts is real work. If there's a good reason to do it, we would, but not just to satisfy idle curiosity.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will keep these questions in mind when I ask my future questions.  Cheers.